function of union of sets = union of functions of sets
If we have say $f:A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$, with $f$ being continuous (I don't think this matters here),
let $S = \{U_k | k \in K \}$ for some set $k \in K$, does the following hold?
$$\bigcup_{u \in S} f(u) = f\left(\bigcup _{u \in S}u\right)$$
for finite S I'm sure this  holds but when is say countable infinte; does this property still hold :)?

Yes. For any family of sets ${(A_{i})}{i\in I}$ where $A{i} \subseteq A$ and a map $f: A\to B$, we have $f\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_{i}\right) = \bigcup_{i\in I}f(A_{i})$.

This holds even if A = R^n, with some set that contains A = R^n as well?

This holds for any set.

Yes, it holds for a collection of sets $S$ of arbitrary cardinality. Let $A_0= \bigcup_{u\in S} f(u),\\ A_1= f\!\left(\bigcup_{u\in S}u\right)\!.$
First we prove that $y\in A_0\implies y\in A_1$. Since $y\in A_0$, there exists a set $u\in S$ such that $y\in f(u)$. Let $x\in u$ be a point such that $f(x)=y$. Note that
$$
x\in u \subset \bigcup_{u\in S} u,
$$
which means $y\in A_1$.
Then we prove the converse $y\in A_1\implies y\in A_0$. Again, let $x\in\bigcup_{u\in S}u$ be a point such that $f(x)=y$. Then there exists a $u\in S$ such that $x\in u$, thus $y\in f(u)$, which is to be proven.

$A'$ is not a great notation as some people use it for the set complement.

Thanks for mentioning that! I changed it to $A_1$ (and $A$ to $A_0$, just to make things symmetric). @JPMcCarthy

Yeah! thanks for the answers :), also i've seen $A'$ been used as the set of limit points as well
